# How to use ZendCache to cache different http methods, GET versus POST?

Tags: http, zend-framework, caching

How can i make Zend Cache make difference between different http methods?

Right now if i make a GET call for example, it's cached and works of course faster after, but if i make a POST call after to the same uri it send me back the data from the last cached GET on this uri.

So basically, i presume it uses the uri as an id for the cached items but not the type of call. What to do in this situation? I have a restfull client that i try to cache results from.

```
    protected function _initCache()
     {

  $dir = APPLICATION_PATH .'/../public/tmp/cache/' ;

         $frontendOptions = array(
             'lifetime' => 10,
             'content_type_memorization' => true,
            'default_options'           => array(
            'cache' => true,
            'cache_with_get_variables' => true,
            'cache_with_post_variables' => true,
            'cache_with_session_variables' => true,
            'cache_with_cookie_variables' => false,
                 'automatic_cleaning_factor' => 0,
             ),
         'regexps' => array(
                 '^/api/' => array('cache' => true),
                 '^/api2/' => array('cache' => true),
                  )
         );

         $backendOptions = array(
                   'cache_dir' =>$dir,
       'hashed_directory_level' => 1
         );

         $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Page',
                              'File',
                              $frontendOptions,
                              $backendOptions);

         Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache($cache);
         Zend_Registry::set('Cache', $cache);

     }
```

Comment: Does it happen automagically? Do you have any code that handles the caching?

Comment: No handler until now. It's on auto. Now i am reading about how to control it. Btw do you know what is the default key used by zend cache on auto?

Comment: Care to elaborate on which Frontend you are using? Page?

Comment: Ok, i added some code i use in my bootstrap.

Answer (score 1):

You have explicitly specified:

```
        'cache_with_get_variables' => true,
        'cache_with_post_variables' => true,
```

So if the $_GET and $_POST variables are the same on both requests you are receiving the same cached result on each request. The easy solution would be to specify a $_POST only argument to differentiate the requests.

Comment: Problem is that is should be a RESTfull Api so i can't differentiate the request other than the method used, am i wrong cause i know i may be?

Comment: I guess using Page cache on a REST Api does not makes much sense. Why don't you use Core or Class or Function instead to cache the demanding operations in your API?

Comment: Can you offer more details? I don't understand exactly. Or at least what should i search for exactly?

Comment: Why would you want to cache the page output on a REST Api? Page caching is used for instance when it requires time/resources to draw a page (such as iterating a huge array to create a table). What is so intense in your case that requires page caching? The json response you are giving out? Could you instead isolate the demanding part and cache that instead? If so you could use Zend_Cache_Core, or Zend_Cache_Frontend_Function (etc) to cache the specific element.

Comment: Thanks, so i must read some more and go in a slightly other direction with this.